# Properties of homeomorphic function

Tags: functions

Is this function homeomorphic and most importantly why?

$$f(x)=x^2$$

What are the properties of homeomorphic functions? When is the function continuous and $1-1$?

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: What do you mean by "homeomorphic function" ?

Comment: It is a function that continuous and bijective

Answer (score 0):

> A function $f : X\to Y$ ($X$ and $Y$ topological spaces) is a homeomorphism iff $f$ is **bijective**, **continuous** and has an inverse function $f^{-1}$ that is continuous.
> (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)

Hence, to study whether $f:x\mapsto x^2$ is a homeomorphism, you have to study if it is bijective and continuous then see if its inverse function is continous.

Then, what is a bijection? Here is a definition for you :

> $f:I\to J$ is **bijective** iff for every element $y$ of $J$, there is an **unique** element $x$ of $I$ verifying $f(x)=y$.

So, at first, is $x^2$ bijective over $\bf{R}$? Then, on which domain can $x^2$ be a homeomorphism?

I hope this can help you start, otherwise don't hesitate to ask specific questions so I can help you.

Comment: Thank you for very scientific answer. 
Would you be so kind to show me on this example how it is done? 
Do I need to define the region R?

Comment: $\bf{R}$ is the common notation for the set of real numbers. In fact, one can easily prove that $x\mapsto x^2$ is not bijective on $\bf{R}$ : you only need to find two different numbers that have the same square. You can begin with that, then I'll accompany you through the next steps !

Comment: Alright.
Say we can have f(2)=4 and f(3)=9. Thus we have 2 different results 4 and 9 which are not equal and thus the function is not bijective. Is this correct? What is step 2? :)

Comment: nope, you need to find two **different** numbers that have the **same** square. For instance, you can search $a$ and $b$ such as $f(a) = f(b) = 4$. Which should be the values for $a$ and $b$ (with $a\neq b$)?

Comment: I guess that there is not such numbers that can satisfy f(a)=f(b)=4 for the given function.And since such numbers doesn't exist the condition of bijection can't be satisfied.

Comment: what about $2$ and $-2$? don't they have the same square? Or $3$ and $-3$?

Comment: Oh, yes. By some reason I was thinking about positive numbers. Thus f(2)=4 and f(-2)=4. What does it says to us then?

Comment: It basically says to us that $x\mapsto x^2$ **is not** bijective over $\bf{R}$. So, in order to prove that it is a homeomorphism, we need to find the largest domain $D$ included in $\bf{R}$ where $x^2$ is bijective. You naturally proposed to take $D = \bf{R_+}$ the set of positive integers, that is a smart choice. Now, the next step is to prove that $x\mapsto x^2$ is bijective for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: And in order to prove it we also need to take any positive numbers? Like f(1)=1 and f(4)=16?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple... To prove that $f$ is bijective, you have to prove that for any $x$ and $y$, you have $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $x=y$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118443/discussion-between-thomas-prevost-and-sergey-dukman).